# Webservice is working in debug mode but not in release mode

Tags: c#, debugging, release

I'm using a web service which works OK in debug mode. When changing to release mode, I get the following exception: `There is an error in XML document (2, 567)`

When looking into the inner exception, the error is:

> Cannot assign object of type R_InsertionOrder.multiple_data_result to
>   an object of type R_Creative.multiple_data_result

The call is :

```
res = oCreativeService.addAttach(a, b, c)
```

(Where `res` is of the same type that the `oCreativeService.addAttach` returns : `R_Creative.multiple_data_result`)

Any idea why my code fails when running in release mode?

Comment: Is `res` explicitly declared as `R_Creative.multiple_data_result`?

Comment: Can you post the code for the method call?  Chances are there's some sort of optimization being done for release mode that is causing an unexpected side-effect.  Also, it might be useful to see the XML (at least the portion throwing the error) if you have it handy.

Answer (score 1):

Edit Project-> Right Click-> Properties-> Build->Generate Serialiazation Assembly Change Value here "Auto" to Off and build on release mode it now works